# Executar programa independente de executável

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou fazendo um updater, mas em certos momentos, preciso atualizar a executável, o que não é possível já que ele está em uso. Teria um modo de trocar os executáveis e executar o programa depois.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, ele encerra o processo, é isso?

Comment: Mas o Application.terminate no meio do programa interrompe todos dos comandos posteriores, não?

Comment: Se fosse .Net teria o ClickOnce.

Comment: @TiagoSilva e como seria? Batch tem suas limitações

Comment: Eu tenho um artigo sobre isso:
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33973

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui fazer, achei uma forma nesse link: http://www.delphibr.com.br/artigos/atualizador.htm

Mais claramente, nessa parte:

```
program Atualizador;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

var
 min: integer;

begin
  DeleteFile('aplicativo.old'); // apaga um arquivo antigo, caso exista
  repeat // o truque: cria-se um laço até encerrar o aplicativo
    if RenameFile('aplicativo.exe','aplicativo.old') then // tenta renomear o exe
    begin
      RenameFile('aplicativo.new','aplicativo.exe'); // renomeia o novo como exe
      WinExec('aplicativo.exe',0); // executa novamente o aplicativo
      exit;
    end;
    min := 0;       // Se não for possível renomear é porque o aplicativo
    sleep(2000);    // não terminou por completo, espero 2 segundos e
    min := min + 1; // tento de novo. Espero até 20 segundos (contador)
 until min = 10;
end.
```

Comment: Sim, mas continua apenas se não atualizar, observe que tem um exit; logo em cima, e só prossegue se não executa-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Caso o executável esteja em uso, pode não conseguir atualizá-lo. Neste caso, se julgar necessário terminar o processo, poderá utilizar a seguinte rotina:

```
Procedure KillProcess( hWindowHandle: HWND );
Var
   hprocessID: INTEGER;
   processHandle: THandle;
   DWResult: DWORD;
Begin
   SendMessageTimeout( hWindowHandle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0,
      SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG Or SMTO_NORMAL, 5000, DWResult );

   If isWindow( hWindowHandle ) Then
   Begin
      // PostMessage(hWindowHandle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
      { Get the process identifier for the window}
      GetWindowThreadProcessID( hWindowHandle, @hprocessID );
      If hprocessID <> 0 Then
      Begin
         { Get the process handle }
         processHandle := OpenProcess( PROCESS_TERMINATE Or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,
            False, hprocessID );
         If processHandle <> 0 Then
         Begin
            { Terminate the process }
            TerminateProcess( processHandle, 0 );
            CloseHandle( ProcessHandle );
         End;
      End;
   End;
End;
```

Atente que esta rotina funcionará quando souber o Handle da janela em execução. Pode ser utilizada a rotina FindWindow da API para auxiliá-lo.